# How much does nutrition affect muscle / joint health?

Tags: muscle, nutrition, injury, injury-prevention, mobility

I've found over the last few years that the amount of problems I've had with trigger points and muscle tightness has been unbelievable. It has really affected my fitness routine as it means I'm often having to modify my routine or cut out certain exercises altogether due to various aches and pains.

I can safely say I never used to have this problem years ago.

I do spend a lot of time sitting (for work etc) but I don't believe the amount of sitting I'm doing quite explains all the problems I've had... and I'm now thinking it might be partly down to my diet.

My diet has admittedly been shocking over the last few years... including way too much sugar, fried / processed foods and take-outs.

Could this be related to all the muscle knots and flexibility / mobility problems interfering with my fitness routine?

Comment: This...is borderline as a question. It might help if we had more details on what your fitness routine actually is, how much time you spend sitting and a little more diet details?

Comment: Lack of magnesium is associated with muscle tightness and studies show most people are deficient thanks to modern diets.

Answer (score -1):

Muscle knots often build up due to the overstressing of fibers and poor posture. This is the indicator that something you're doing to your body is not right. That might be related to physical aspects as well as nutrition involvement. To keep your muscles strong and healthy make sure you're not deficient to Vitamin D. So I'd urge you to keep track of the vitamins essential for normal functioning of the body, here https://sportsinside.co.uk/blogs/magazine/vitamins-for-energy you can list of those which are directly related with improving energy in the body. Taking them by natural diet is the best way to keep your life balanced, otherwise taking through supplements can also be helpful if you've much deficiency of them.